# How to print a webpage while omitting an html table in the page?

Tags: internet, printing, html

I want to print some online documentation, but at the end of each documentation, there is some links, etc that would be useless on a paper. I looked at the source code of the page and they all use the same table name for that section.

Something that would be even better is if I can save these html pages and remove the tables and then combine everything in a pdf so I wouldn't have to print pages that aren't filling the page on one page. But that's another issue.

Right now, I just want to omit this table from the print, and since there are 100s of links, don't want to manually edit each page on disk.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PrintWhatYouLike.com](http://printwhatyoulike.com/), which lets you remove arbitrary elements from a page before printing it or saving in to a PDF.  They even have a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) that lets you go directly to their page printer/editor from the page you want to print.

Comment: NOTE: This only works for publicly visible Web pages.  You can't use it, for instance, to print HTML docs on your disk or pages served from a private Web server on your intranet.

Comment: That's ok, but I have 100s of pages to print, so this would still take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

If you use chrome, you can rightclick, inspect elements, and delete what don't want to print, then hit the print button.

In firefox, you can do the same if firebug is installed.

Comment: Can I do it automatically with firebug? Because there are 100s of pages and I don't want to delete them one by one.

Comment: Probably not. You could install Stylish and make a userstyle that removes it for whatever domains you'd like.